# Limit of 2 variable piecewise function at $(0, 0)$ along $y = x$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am a little confused regarding the limit for a 2 variable piecewise function.

The function is this:
$$
f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases} 
      0, & xy\ne 0\\
      1, & xy = 0 
   \end{cases}
\
$$

I am trying to take the limit as (x, y) approaches (0, 0) along the line $y = x$, but I am a little confused.

From what I can tell, the function will be discontinuous at the point (0, 0), but no matter what line you approach the point (0, 0) on, you will get the same value, 0.

If someone wouldnt mind explaining how I would go about proving if the limit exists or not, I would be very grateful.

Thanks
Corey

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it isn't true that the limit of the function is $0$ along whatever line passing through $(0,0)$. For the lines $x=0$ or $y=0$, the limit is equal to $1$.

However, you can find discontinuous functions at the origin for which the limit exists along all lines passing through the origin. You can have a look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuity-multivariable-real-functions/).